# disable alt ctrl Fn in linux

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, xterm

first I apologize for my pure language skills.
I have a system based on debian. I disable all virtual terminal in /etc/inittab file except tty1.
In tty1 I run xinit (that uses xterm for X client) and then on X window that opens I run my program.

the bad thing is when user press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>, system switchs to a black page. but I want disable this feature.

how can I disable <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd> shortcuts?!

Thank you...

Solution:
thanks from Klaas van Gend for his answer.
I wrote the complete solution in this place.
I go to /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/srvr_ctrl and delete all line in xkb_symbols “fkey2vt” block.
then all <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd> disapear.
attention: This solution works when you want to disable shortcuts in X. but if you want disable this shortcuts in terminal mode, this solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can remove the function keys from the keymap.
See e.g. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=188761

Comment: I dont want to change my layout. I want to remove shortcut key somehow it does not work anywhere! but this post is about changing layout.

Comment: A keyboard layout hooks keycodes to meanings. Nothing more. If you remove a key from the layout, there is no meaning, hence your system will not respond to it.